# Backbone.js login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

My app is created in Backbone.js and I use ajax in the log in process, where in this case I don't have any model (which I'm not sure if that's, umm appropriate). The ajax submits the user input on a cross-domain which in return gives me status codes, based on this I'll determine where the user needs to be redirected. I've been searching over the net on how to change the entire page on success after the user has logged in.

So far I have a working log in and registration though they don't redirect as they need to be and working routes for the extra pages that I need.

Any chance you could give advice on backbone.js is much appreciated as I'm still trying to learn it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to change the views I guess.

Comment: I need to change the entire page, ie from `index.html` to `home.html` I use the views only if I don't need to reload the page. The examples that I have encountered so far uses model, which confuses me cause (correct me if I'm wrong) models are the ones responsible for manipulating data, where in my case I leave those matters to my cross-domain ajax that's why I don't have a model for my project.

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: I'm trying to do it by changing the whole `#pagewrap` div using views, where in this case it will only require me one html file. I'm still figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a separate view & template for the `login` where the user has to input his credentials and `home` when login is successful. I have a `#pagewrap` div that contains the whole template of both views, if login successful I'll just call the `home.html` template, if not then it will be `login.html` template

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same but have issues, can you please share your code if its an open source project

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
window.location.href("#home")
```

if #home is the view you want to land in, after a successful login

In your router, handle #home and call the appropriate function to load the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Backbone`, you will have another more decent solution which is `Router`. After successfully logging in, you can call this call to navigate user to a new page.

```
router.navigate("afterLogin", {trigger: true});
```

And in your `router`, you can have something like this

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "afterLogin": 'afterLogin'
  },

  afterLogin: function() {
    // now render the whole page all over gain
  }

});
```